# Set every label node to his north west position

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

Is there a way in order to set every label of every single node to his north west position?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style={draw},
    mylabel/.style={label={above left:{#1}}}
    ]
    \node[mylabel={Where}] (a) {is};
    \node[mylabel={your}, right=4em of a] {MWE?};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: :) Great answer!

Comment: @marmot Hoping to find an MWE in the OP's next question :):):)

Comment: Grazie Carla! =)

Comment: @AndreaLeo Prego, and please remember to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) next time!